# Is there an equivilent for 'old' notepad?

Tags: windows, text-editor

I mean, I guess I can get a copy of notepad.exe from an older system - but I'm wondering if there's a maintained alternative. Current notepad is gradually getting bloaty (I like tabs, but I have sublime text for that!, and I don't want [AI in my text editor](https://lifehacker.com/tech/copilot-in-notepad-windows-11))

There's a few 'modern' niceties I wouldn't say no to either

The minimum I want is basically... notepad as it was before the new tabbed version

- No tabs. I want one document per window
- I don't want a programmer's text editor with line number and highlighting
- Some customisability (fonts/font sizes/dark mode) is optional but not necessary
- Gratis
- Runs on windows 10/11
- no extra features. I have a perfectly good full fat text editor. I need a very diet one.

Comment: Unicode support? You can just use `copy con myfile.txt` in a console :-D

Comment: Probably even https://www.notepadsapp.com/ is too much tabs. How about https://liquidninja.com/metapad/ ? Even https://github.com/zufuliu/notepad2 gets more and more features. What maintenance does a program need, if you don't want extra features? You could easily use Notepad2 from 2012 and probably you're good to go.

Comment: I used to run Q10 as my main editor for a bit, and I vaguely recall while core functionality was fine, it gradually started crashing and such.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Notepad3](https://rizonesoft.com/downloads/notepad3/) and its precursors (incl. Notepad2) for years. It's fast, simple and meets your requirements, although it does have syntax highlighting and it can add line numbers etc. But if you don't want to use that stuff, you don't have to.

Comment: With the proper settings you can turn Notepad3 into just Notepad, no extra features need to be enabled.